# Getting full $error output with line number

Tags: powershell

I have a very large PowerShell script that when I use $error at the end of the script, I am getting a returned error, even though the Transcript is not showing one. So I have no clue where the "error" is at. Here is my setup:

```
$error.Clear()

# 600 lines of code

foreach ($err_msg IN $error) {
    $body += "<br><hr>"
    $body += "$err_msg"
}
```

It then sends that in an email to me. The issue I am having is it returns an error somewhere in the code that is not visible in Start-Transcript but I want to clean it up so its not reporting this error to me every night. If I just run $error in the console, I get line numbers for errors, but if I use the above code to log the errors, I do not get line numbers. Any way to display the full error with line numbers without using try/catch?

Comment: Unless you use `-ErrorAction Ignore` or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'`, the `$Error` variable will populate with any errors detected (this includes non-script-terminating ones).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 After doing what Shawn said below, I found it was actual a module causing an error that was set to silently continue. So that is why I wasn't able to track it down.

Comment: I figured as much, just wanted to be informative on the actions of the `$Error` automatic variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could format the errors using `Select-Object` and then convert it to an html table using `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment`

```
if ( $error )
{
    $ErrorTable = $Error | Select-Object -Property @(
        @{Name = 'ScriptLineNumber'; Expression = { $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber } }
        @{Name = 'Line'            ; Expression = { $_.InvocationInfo.Line } }
        @{Name = 'Exception'       ; Expression = { $_.Exception } }
    ) | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

    $Body += "<br><hr>"
    $Body += $ErrorTable
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was just text.. Didn't realize it had other properties! I typically use ISE and put a "." and if nothing comes up, I just assume it has no other properties. Just learned something new!